# returning data from controller to VIEW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

ii am told to create a login system in MVC 3 using old traditional sql queries etc, i have created login but problem is that i'm returning data from model to View . I have created datatable in model and returning it to controller, successfully but don't know that how to show that data on view ? have searched good but didn't help.

MODEL :

```
public ConnectionStatus Login_db(String email, String pwd, String conStr)
{
    String hashedpwd_login = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(pwd, "SHA1");
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand())
        {
            sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCom.CommandText = "select Count(*) from tblRegister where userEmail=@email AND userPwd=@pwd";
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", hashedpwd_login);
            String select_com = "select * from tblRegister";
            SqlCommand sqlCom2 = new SqlCommand(select_com, sqlCon);
            ConnectionStatus connectStatus = new ConnectionStatus();
            int no_rows_affected;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select_com, sqlCon);
            DataTable data_tb = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                no_rows_affected = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
                if (no_rows_affected == 1)
                {
                    connectStatus.Message = "User logged in successfully, " + no_rows_affected;
                    sda.Fill(data_tb);
                    tableCreation tb_creation = new tableCreation();
                    tb_creation.CreateTable = data_tb;
                }
                else 
                {
                    connectStatus.Message = "Invalid email/password combination.";
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return connectStatus;

        }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult loginResult(String command, FormCollection formData) 
{
    if (command == "Login")
    {
        var email = formData["txtboxEmail"];
        var pwd = formData["txtboxPassword"];
   //     String conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";
        database model_db = new database();
        var db_status = model_db.Login_db(email, pwd, conStr);
        ViewBag.Message = db_status.Message;


    }
    tableCreation retTable = new tableCreation();
    return View(retTable.CreateTable);
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login Authentication";
}

<h2>Login Authentication</h2>

<h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4>
```

Note: some classes are user defined for multi purposes.

Comment: Can you please explain, what you want to display in table and from where you are getting information for that table

Comment: String select_com = "select * from tblRegister";

Comment: possible duplicate of [extracting data from DATASET in view layer of MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878881/extracting-data-from-dataset-in-view-layer-of-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebGrid in MVC3. This is new in MVC3. Use this code in your View.

```
@model IList<YourViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login Information";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 200, 
    canPage: false, canSort: true, defaultSort: "Absentee");
 }
<p>
    <h2>Absentee List</h2>
        <div id="grid">
            @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", 
                new { id =   item.Id     })), 
                grid.Column("Absentee", "Absentee",canSort:true),
                grid.Column("AbsStart", "AbsStartDate")
            ))
      </div>
  </p>
```