# extracting data from DATASET in view layer of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

i am told t use old traditional way of SQL in MVC so created login register page but now problem is that i can't return data to VIEW from dataset.

Model:

```
public ConnectionStatus Login_db(String email, String pwd, String conStr)
        {
            String hashedpwd_login = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(pwd, "SHA1");
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
                    sqlCom.CommandText = "select Count(*) from tblRegister where userEmail=@email AND userPwd=@pwd";
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", hashedpwd_login);
                    String select_com = "select * from tblRegister";
                    SqlCommand sqlCom2 = new SqlCommand(select_com, sqlCon);
                    ConnectionStatus connectStatus = new ConnectionStatus();
                    int no_rows_affected;
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(select_com, sqlCon);
                    DataSet data_tb = new DataSet();

                    try
                    {
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        no_rows_affected = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
                        if (no_rows_affected == 1)
                        {
                            connectStatus.Message = "User logged in successfully, " + no_rows_affected;
                            sda.Fill(data_tb, "tblRegister");
                            tableCreation tb_creation = new tableCreation();
                            tb_creation.CreateTable = data_tb;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            connectStatus.Message = "Invalid email/password combination.";
                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        connectStatus.Message = ex.Message;
                    }
                    return connectStatus;

                }
```

controller

```
 public ActionResult loginResult(String command, FormCollection formData) 
        {
            if (command == "Login")
            {
                var email = formData["txtboxEmail"];
                var pwd = formData["txtboxPassword"];
           //     String conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";
                database model_db = new database();
                var db_status = model_db.Login_db(email, pwd, conStr);
                ViewBag.Message = db_status.Message;


            }
            tableCreation retTable = new tableCreation();
            ViewData["DataTable"] = retTable.CreateTable;
            return View(retTable.CreateTable);
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login Authentication";

}

@model System.Data.DataSet

<h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4>


@foreach (var row in Model.Tables["tblRegister"].Rows)
{    
    @(row["userID"] + " " + row["userName"])
}
```

note that i created tableCreation classes etc to pass dataset object so i can create it object in controller.

Comment: You shouldn't be using any DataSets. Instead define a model.

Comment: i know but i am told to use and do it like this way

Comment: so help me in this context

Comment: Sure, checkout my answer.

Comment: yes sir it's a great way... Much appreciated but as i told you that i'm told to use it that way like using datatable adn adapters, consider it a challenge for me that has been given, and i surely will try ur code after solving my this particular issue, I fu can help then PLEASE\

Comment: No sorry I cannot help in this case. I simply don't want to contribute with wrong code on StackOveflow. Can you imagine if someone else is attempting to do the same thing and comes to this thread? We don't want him to be making such huge mistakes as you are about to do with DataTables and adapters.

Comment: yeah that sounds good but can u tel me that if something works and can be done than how come that it's wrong practice ?

Comment: DataTables are weakly typed collections that do not fit into the ASP.NET MVC pattern. Also if they *work* why are you posting this question here?

Answer (score 6):

You should not use DataSets and SqlDataAdapters in ASP.NET MVC. You should use models instead.

So let me try to rewrite your code. Start by defining the model that will represent your entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

you could also have a `ConnectionStatus` model:

public class ConnectionStatus
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set }
}

and then your data layer might contain 2 methods (one for verifying the credentials and one for getting the list of users):

```
public static class Db
{
    public static ConnectionStatus<bool> Login(string email, string password, string connectionString)
    {
        string hasedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM tblRegister WHERE userEmail=@email AND userPwd=@pwd";
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", hasedPassword);

            var status = new ConnectionStatus<bool>();
            status.Result = false;
            try
            {
                int rowsFound = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
                if (rowsFound == 1)
                {
                    status.Result = true;
                    status.Message = "User logged in successfully, " + rowsFound;
                }
                else
                {
                    status.Message = "Invalid email/password combination.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return status;
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionStatus<IList<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT userID, userName FROM tblRegister";

            var status = new ConnectionStatus<IList<User>>();
            status.Result = new List<User>();

            try
            {
                using (var reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var user = new User();
                        user.Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("userID"));
                        user.Email = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("userName"));
                        status.Result.Add(user);  
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

and then define a view model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string TxtboxEmail { get; set; }
    public string TxtboxPassword { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
public ActionResult LoginResult(LoginViewModel model) 
{
    if (model.Command == "Login")
    {
        string conStr = "Data Source=HUNAIN-PC;Initial Catalog=registration;User ID=sa;Password=abc123!@#";
        var loginStatus = Db.Login(model.TxtboxEmail, model.TxtboxPassword, conStr);
        ViewBag.Message = loginStatus.Message;
    }

    var usersStatus = Db.GetUsers(conStr);
    return View(usersStatus.Result);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model IList<User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login Authentication";
}

<h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4>

<table>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@user.Id</td>
            <td>@user.Email</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: ok thanks and i learned a lot but could u explain the code, this one, Have u used LINQ or soemthing bcz i still can see traditional SQL so LINQ might not be there i guess but please explain a bit

Comment: No, I haven't used LINQ. That's plain ADO.NET SQL. I thought that was your requirement - to use plain ADO.NET instead of an ORM such as Entity Framework?

Comment: great but what are these angle brackets for ? <> ? never saw that