# I want to pass two dates as parameter to stored procedure and display my table as its in view in mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This my code where my passing dates and I want to display the data from the table as its from sql to view in ASP.NET MVC 5. And that two dates are also comes from view means after selecting this dates I have to pass it into the parameter in stored procedure

```
public DataTable Get_Availability(string ID = "")
{
  string aDate = "03/03/2017";
  string dDate = "20/03/2017";
  DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(aDate);
  DateTime uDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dDate);

  queryString = "FO.USP_Check_AvailabilityOFRoom";

  try
  {
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Date_Of_Birth",Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
        cmd.Parameters("@Date_Of_Birth").Value = DOB

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds != null && ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
          if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
          {
             return ds.Tables[0];
          }
        }
     }
  }
  catch
  {
     return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Please check your code formatting and add an explanation what the exact problem is at the moment. What is not working?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279547/how-to-display-database-records-in-asp-net-mvc-view?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: What is the error you are getting can u elaborate it ... You can use parameters like this way "FO.USP_Check_AvailabilityOFRoom '"+"03/03/2017"+"','"+"20/03/2017"+"'"

Comment: return the dataset to view and display the table. there are many ways. go thorugh this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878881/extracting-data-from-dataset-in-view-layer-of-mvc

Comment: i have two dates and i want to pass that dates as a parametere to stored procedure and store procedure give table  and i want that table e.g. i have arrival date and departure date of hotel i want to pass that dates to the stored procedure

Comment: Try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/datatable-in-viewdata-sample-in-mvc-day-3/

Comment: how to pass dates to stored procedure as parameter in above code

Comment: from where you want to get the dates either user or constant if you want to get it from user pass in method parameters and use jquery call the method

Comment: please give me example

Comment: problem solve. thank you!  cmd.Parameters.Add("@arrDate", oDate) ;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@depDate", uDate);

Comment: Remove commented code in sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parametername", date);
```

`@parametername` is parameter in you SP.
`date` is your date variable.